# What is the C++/CLI equivalent for the 'const ' keyword in C#?

Tags: c++-cli

I tried to declare the following in my C++/CLI code.

```
public ref class MyClass
{
public:
    const String ^MyLuckyNumber = "One";
```

It fails misirably during the compile phase. But in C# the following works.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public const string NowMyLuckyNumber = "Two";
```

How can I declare a 'const String^' in C++/CLI?
I tried to google on it but no luck!

Comment: I don't know C++/CLI, but try `String ^const MyLuckyNumber = "One";`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the keyword you're looking for is `literal`

```
literal String ^MyLuckyNumber = "One";
```

the `literal` keyword implies a `static const` on the variable you're declaring.  Also, the keyword requires an initialization during the declaration, something you'd expect from a `static const` declaration.

[MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5yzft952.aspx)

Comment: If, like me, you want to create a C++/CLI struct containing just constants, you must #include the header file in a cpp file somewhere in your C++/CLI library, otherwise the struct definition is not included in the library.